# What is the "Image" object?

Tags: standard-objects, object

While browsing the Object Manager I found the "Image" object. However, I couldn't find any documentation for it and it's not mentioned in the [list of standard objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_list.htm). What is it good for? Where is it used?

[image: Screenshot of image object]

Answer (score 5):

Salesforce has introduced Consumer Goods Cloud, a new industry product that enables companies related to consumer goods to optimize revenue growth and maximize ROI with the help of advanced retail technique adoption.

Image Object is available in API version 47.0 and later.

[Image Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.retail_api.meta/retail_api/industries_einstein_api_objects_image.htm)

[Consumer Goods Cloud](https://www.salesforce.com/company/news-press/press-releases/2019/09/191609-cg/#:~:text=Consumer%20Goods%20Cloud%20is%20part,chain%20with%20a%20unified%20platform.)