# What criteria does Salesforce use in the Object Manager to list the SObjects?

Tags: setup

On Setup => Object Manager, there is a list of SObjects.

However does anyone know which filtering criteria does Salesforce use to show/hide the SObjects from the complete list of the Org SObjects?

For instance, the Image SObject appears in the list. This SObject also has a Lookup to the Content Document SObject, nonetheless, it does not appear in the list of the Object Manager.

Answer (score 1):

According to the article "[Find Object Management Settings in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.extend_click_find_objectmgmt_lex.htm&type=5)"

> Some standard objects aren’t housed in the Object Manager. Standard objects with more specific purposes and customizations can be found in Setup using the Quick Find box.
> From Setup, enter the object name in the Quick Find box, then select the customization.

`Content Document` is one of those standard object which has a specific purpose and cannot be "customized" to allow adding new fields or update page layout.

If you want to add custom fields on related content documents, then you have to customize `Content Version` object, which is available in Object Manager.

Regarding Image object, refer to this other post [What is Image Object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308057/what-is-the-image-object)

Comment: Yeah, sure. However is there any way I can use [the properties of the SObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_describeGlobal.htm) to determine which SObject have a specific purpose and can be customized?
Or is this a hardcoded list?

Comment: @Meir The Get List of objects API will normally just list all the objects available in your org, but it might be better to ask a different question about this and share more detail on what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: [Updated question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347910/how-can-i-get-the-sobject-list-shown-in-the-object-manager-through-the-rest-api)