# How can I get the SObject list shown in the Object Manager through the REST API?

Tags: setup

When making a GET request to the sobjects endpoint we get a list of all the sobjects available in the Org.

However I would like to get the same list of sobjects as the one shown through the Object Manager.

Any ideas about how can I do this?